# can't enable postgis extensions like postgis_topology and postgis on mac after installation

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

I have installed postgres and postgis as described [here](http://morphocode.com/how-to-install-postgis-on-mac-os-x/)

```
brew install postgres
brew install postgis

createdb postgis_test
psql postgis_test

psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgis_test=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not stat file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis--2.3.2.sql": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory
```

What might be the error ? and how to solve it ?

Comment: There are tons of results in google for this error for me. Did you make any research before posting it here?

Comment: ofcourse i have searched it, but couldn't able to find anything related to it and hence i posted it here , can you provide me best result for this ?

Comment: `could not open extension control file` means that the extension is not installed, at least not in the PostgreSQL software directory. Investigate along these lines: check where PostGIS was installed, ask the packagers for help.

Comment: I have installed postgis using homebrew and when  i check `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();` i got `LINE 1: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` does this mean postgres not installed ?

Comment: @shivakrishna, did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @Spider Yes completely uninstalled postgres and re installed it

Comment: I would also like to know what to do about this one...